# Use sed/grep to get string from tail to a char in middle

Tags: string, bash, sed, grep

I have some strings (variables) i need to edit in the bash for further analysis
They consist of things like

```
str="~/folder/item"
```

How can I use `sed` or `grep` to grab just "item" (meaning from tail to char '/')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).  You can say:

```
$ str="~/folder/item"
$ echo ${str##*/}
item
```

Quoting from the manual:

> `${parameter##word}`
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
>   expansion (see Filename Expansion). If the pattern matches the
>   beginning of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the
>   expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest
>   matching pattern (the ‘`#`’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the
>   ‘`##`’ case) deleted. If parameter is ‘`@`’ or ‘`*`’, the pattern removal
>   operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the
>   expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable
>   subscripted with ‘`@`’ or ‘`*`’, the pattern removal operation is applied
>   to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the
>   resultant list.

---

Using `grep`:

```
$ grep -Po '.*/\K.*' <<< $str
item
```

Comment: Please can you explain line-2? p.s. +1

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are dealing with a text file containing lines like the one shown, then:

```
sed 's%.*/\([^/]*\)"%\1%' <<< 'str="~/folder/item"'
```

This yields:

```
item
```

If you are dealing with a variable `str` that contains a string `~/folder/item`, then you can use:

```
basename "$str"
```

or:

```
echo "${str##*/}"
```

Answer (score 1):

`basename "${str}"` gives the last part of the string after the final `/`, including any file extensions you may have. If you want to do the opposite and grab the directory, use `dirname "${str}"`

Answer (score 0):

basename also suitable for this

for example

```
str="~/folder/item" 
name=$(basename $file)
echo $name
```

the output would be "item"

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $str|awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'
```

or

```
echo "$str" | perl -pe 's/.*\///g'
```